# Problem with nonexistent return statement in ZeroDivisionError in Python

Tags: python, return

i've been doing the "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python Programming" course, and I don't understand why author says that the reason of None value being in output is a fact, that there is no return statement in function below. I I thought that "return 42/divideBy" is a return statement that is needed. I am very much new in the world of programming, so i would appreciate an easy explanation. Thanks

```
def div42by (divideBy):
try:
    return 42/divideBy
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print ('Error: You tried to divide by zero.')
print (div42by(2))
print (div42by(12))
print (div42by(0))
print (div42by(1))

(output)
21.0
3.5
Error: You tried to divide by zero.
None
42.0
```

Comment: Code formatting issues aside, your code has a `try/except` block. If the `try` portion succeeds, it does `return 42/divideBy`. If an exception is raised, it does a `print` and then the method is completed. In that case, Python adds an implicit `return` from the method, and a naked `return` statement means you return `None`. Please read through the [defining functions tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) which does describe this.

Comment: a function without an explicit  (and not `None`) `return` statement returns always `None`. Once a `return` is executed the execution of the function is finished. A `try/expect` acts as a "switch" and in the `except` block, and after, there is no further `return` so assumed `None`. If you get `None` means that a division by zero took place. So, a "non existent return" is just an implicit return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that `return 42/divideBy` is a return statement.

But when `divideBy` is **equal to zero**, the `42/divideBy` part will raise a `ZeroDivisionError`, which means the `return` **never actually runs**. Instead, Python jumps to the `print ('Error: You tried to divide by zero.')` line and continues running from there. There's no `return` statement after that line, so Python automatically returns `None` instead.

Another way to look at it is that your `div42by` function is equivalent to this:

```py
def div42by(divideBy):
    try:
        result = 42 / divideBy
        return result
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Error: You tried to divide by zero.')
```

And the `return result` line never runs when `divideBy` is zero.

Answer (score -1):

The return statement is not executed because dividing by zero raises an ZeroDivisionError.
This ZeroDivisionError is then caught by the try->except block.

The order in which things happen is:

- python3 tries to execute `42 / divideBy` (which is zero)
- `42 / divideBy` raises the ZeroDivisionError
- the ZeroDivisionError is caught by the try-except
- the except-block is executed, making python3 print the error message
- the function continues, but there is no Code left
- No return statement gets executed

To still get a return, there'd need to be a return statement below try->except but still inside the function.